# Accessing video from another machine in Struts2 Java

Tags: java, jsp, video, struts2, remote-access

I am trying to display a video stored on another machine through my application using embed tag.So far I have been successfull in accessing the video which is saved on another machine's server. However I am trying to find a way by which I can access a video saved in any other drive but I get an error

> HTTP Status 404

Please find the below code I have tried.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Video Test</title>

</head>
<body>


<embed src="http://ip:port/project/Wildlife.wmv" width="370" height="270" >
</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine for videos stored on server. Please guide.

Comment: Define *saved in any other drive*.

Comment: In other drive means say D drive in a different machine...

Comment: You can't map it in the url.

Comment: So what can be the possible solutions?

Comment: Stream it via a `"stream"` result or write directly to the result, just like any other out-of-app resource. If it's not on the server machine you need to figure out how to get it accessible, either via a service on the other machine, some form of network drive mapping, etc. I mean, come on, you can't magically access resources on random machines.